# When is an algebraic space a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Sometimes general theory is "good" at showing that a functor is representable by an algebraic spaces (e.g., Hilbert functors, Picard functors, coarse moduli spaces, etc).  What sort of general techniques are there to show that an algebraic space is a scheme?  Sometimes it's possible to identify your algebraic space with something "else" (e.g. it "comes" from GIT as is the case for the moduli space of curves), but are there other methods?

Answer (score 20):

One result along those lines is that that any algebraic space which has a quasi-finite morphism to a scheme is itself a scheme.

More precisely, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a separated, finite type, quasi-finite morphism of algebraic spaces, then the Stein factorization $X\to \mathrm{Spec}_Y(f_*\mathcal{O}_X)\to Y$ is an open immersion followed by an affine morphism, so $f$ is quasi-affine. In particular, if $Y$ is a scheme, so is $X$.

#### References

This is Proposition 3.1 of [Quot Functors for Deligne-Mumford Stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204307) or Théorème A.2 of [Champs algébriques](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540657613).

I learned this from Martin Olsson; it's Corollary 17.8 in [my notes from his stacks course](https://github.com/geraschenko/Stacks/blob/master/Stacks.pdf). It's Theorem 7.2.10 in [the book](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-62) he's since written covering the material from that course. Jason Starr points out that there's a mistake in Lemma 6.2.9 which propagates to this theorem (I haven't checked this), and suggested the two alternative references above.

Comment: Cool!  Then one might wonder how to produce "enough line bundles" on X to start trying to make these maps to something projective, for example.  Or simply how to make them in general.

Comment: @Anton: the link to your notes doesn't work. Are these still available somewhere?

Comment: @katalaveino Thanks for the ping. I've updated the link.

Comment: I am only posting this because I noticed this answer has recently been updated.  There is a mistake in Lemma 6.2.9, which I believe propagates to the proof of Stein factorization for algebraic spaces. It would be better to use Proposition 3.1 of my article with Olsson.  It would be best to use the correct source: Theoreme A.2, p. 198 of Laumon and Moret-Bailly.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks! I've just added those references as well.

Answer (score 12):

Another example: the [Nakai-Moishezon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ample_line_bundle#Criteria_for_ampleness) theorem says that a divisor D on X is ample iff for every curve C on D, $D \cdot C > 0$ and $D^2 > 0$. This holds also for an algebraic space.

As an application, you can show for instance that the coarse space of $\bar{M_g}$, the Deligne-Mumford compactification of the moduli stack of smooth genus g curves, is represented by a projective variety. The point is that Artin's representibility theorem tells you that the coarse space exists as an algebraic space, and you can then use Nakai-Moishezon to show that it has an ample line bundle. This is cool because it avoids GIT.

Comment: Ah, cool!  Doing a little research I see that Koll\'ar has done exactly this in his paper "Projectivity of Complete Moduli".  You let $D$ to be a power of the relative dualizing sheaf.  Then for curves $C$ not contained in the boundary it's more or less clear the Nakai-Moishezon condition is satisfied and for curves contained in the boundary you work a little harder but it's still true.  He also applies this to compactifications of surfaces of general type.  Are there other known applications of this method?

Comment: One is David Smyth's thesis. Its similar though, he gives alternative compactificaitons of $\bar{M_{g,n}}$ and shows that they have projetive coarse moduli spaces (here GIT doesn't work).

Answer (score 6):

One example: an algebraic space $X$ is a scheme iff $X_{\text{red}}$ is a scheme.

One application of this is that a quotient (I may be missing an adjective or two here) by a reductive group over an Artin ring is a scheme. Call the quotient $X$. Then it is easy to prove that $X$ is an algebraic space. On the other hand when your Artin ring is a field the classical theory of reductive groups tells you that the quotient is a scheme, i.e. $X_{\text{red}}$ is a scheme, and you can conclude that $X$ is in fact a scheme.

Comment: How do you show that X is a scheme if X_{red} is? I remember we worked this out before, but I don't remember how. I feel like the first thing to do (assuming X is noetherian) is to reduce to showing that a square-zero thickening of a scheme is a scheme.

Comment: I believe this is in Knutson's book.

Comment: If $X$ is noetherian and locally separated, this is Corollary III.3.6 of Knutson's book Algebraic Spaces.

Comment: Apparently the noetherian and locally separated hypotheses are not needed: http://mathoverflow.net/q/195528.