# Algebraic space birational to a scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-spaces

Let $S$ be a Noetherian scheme, let $Y$ be a scheme of finite type over $S$, and let $X$ be an algebraic space of finite type over $S$. Suppose that there is a morphism $f:Y \rightarrow X$ which is proper and birational. Must $X$ be a scheme?

See also 
[When is an algebraic space a scheme?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4573/when-is-an-algebraic-space-a-scheme)

Comment: No, that is not true.  In fact, the opposite is true if you add a few hypotheses (e.g., if S is a finite type scheme over a field or over an excellent DVR, and if the algebraic space $X$ is separated).  This is often called "Chow's Lemma for algebraic spaces".  There is a reference in Knutson's "Algebraic Spaces" . . .

Comment: . . . I forget to look up the reference earlier.  Here it is: Chow's Lemma, Theorem IV.3.1, p. 192, Donald Knutson, "Algebraic Spaces", LNM 203, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1971.

Comment: Thank  you very much. Can you post it as an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just posting my comment as an answer.  Chow's Lemma for algebraic spaces is Theorem IV.3.1, p. 192 of the following.

MR0302647 (46 #1791) 
Knutson, Donald 
Algebraic spaces. 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 203. 
Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1971. vi+261 pp.

For every separated, Noetherian scheme $S$, for every finitely presented, separated morphism of algebraic spaces, $X\to S$, there exists a morphism $f:Y\to X$ that is projective and birational such that $Y\to S$ is a quasi-projective morphism.