# Bijective to algebraic space implies isomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $Y$ be a smooth algebraic space proper over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume $f:X \to Y$ is a morphism such that bijective on $\mathbb{C}$-points.

Question: Is $f$ an isomorphism? Hence $Y$ is a variety?

When $Y$ is already a variety, this is true from Zariski's Main Theorem (see for example [Bijection implies isomorphism for algebraic varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264204/bijection-implies-isomorphism-for-algebraic-varieties)).

Comment: $Y$ can be considered a compact complex manifold by Artin and then $f$ is a holomorphic bijection. Holomorphic bijections have holomorphic inverses.

Comment: @virkkunen Thanks! Is there any reference about this fact? I mean consider $Y$ as a complex manifold?

Comment: By miracle flatness (Matsumura, Comm. Ring Theory, Thm 23.1) the morphism $f$ is flat, hence open, hence a homeomorphism, so $Y$ is integral.

Comment: The same proof from the answer that you link works for algebraic spaces as well as for schemes: Zariski's Main Theorem works for algebraic spaces.

Comment: @MatthieuRomagny the question is not whether $Y$ is integral (as opposed to just of finite type), but whether $Y$ is even a scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Not an answer to the question. I confused the roles of $X$ and $Y$.

If $X\to Y$ is a quasi-finite separated morphism of algebraic spaces and $Y$ is a scheme, then $X$ is a scheme.

This is, as Jason Starr already commented, a consequence of Zariski's Main Theorem for algebraic spaces.

You are thus reduced to the case of varieties.

Comment: I believe the more relevant result has hypothesis that $X$ is a scheme, rather than that $Y$ is a scheme, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4573/when-is-an-algebraic-space-a-scheme/4574

Comment: @JasonStarr Whoops, you are right. I misread the roles of $X$ and $Y$.